# What cards give +1/+1 counters to all friendly creatures?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I wonder if there is any card that gives +1/+1 counters to all creature I have on the field? I have [Krenko, Mob Boss](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Krenko%2C%20Mob%20Boss), [Abzan Battle Priest](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Abzan%20Battle%20Priest) and [Mirror Entity](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mirror%20Entity) so it would be awesome to have +1/+1 counters on all my goblins.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[*Ajani Goldmane*](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=205957)'s -1 ability will give counters to all your creatures and also give them vigilance until end of turn:

> **−1**: Put a +1/+1 counter on each creature you control. Those creatures gain vigilance until end of turn.

[*Ajani Steadfast*](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=383180)'s -2 ability will also give counters to all your creatures

> **−2**: Put a +1/+1 counter on each creature you control and a loyalty counter on each other planeswalker you control.

[*Abzan Ascendancy*](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386464) also gives +1/+1 counters to all creatures you have on the battlefield at that moment:

> When Abzan Ascendancy enters the battlefield, put a +1/+1 counter on each creature you control.

[*Archangel of Thune*](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=370627) will work awesome with [*Abzan Battle Priest*](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386466)(the one you already have):

> Whenever you gain life, put a +1/+1 counter on each creature you control.

[*Borborygmos*](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=97229) may also be used to get +1/+1 counters. And it's a big *6/7 Trample* creature

> Whenever Borborygmos deals combat damage to a player, put a +1/+1 counter on each creature you control.

But [*Cathars' Crusade*](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=389459) might actually be (one of the) best for your scenario. That card and [*Krenko, Mob Boss*](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=386339)... I'm adding red to my Abzan deck!

> Whenever a creature enters the battlefield under your control, put a +1/+1 counter on each creature you control.

[*Celestial Ancient*](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=271236) can also give +1/+1 counters to all your creatures:

> Whenever you cast an enchantment spell, put a +1/+1 counter on each creature you control.

[*Decree of Savagery*](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=46423) for **four +1/+1 counters**

> Put four +1/+1 counters on each creature you control.

[*Mikaeus, the Lunarch*](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=247234) a *Legendary Human Cleric* that will only cost you 2 mana to get a +1/+1 counter on all your creatures(Mikaeus might die in process)

> {T}, Remove a +1/+1 counter from Mikaeus: Put a +1/+1 counter on each other creature you control.

[*Phalanx Leader*](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=373592)'s *Heroic* ability can also give all your creatures a +1/+1 counter

> Heroic — Whenever you cast a spell that targets Phalanx Leader, put a +1/+1 counter on each creature you control.

[*Tempt With Glory*](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=376543)

> Tempting offer — Put a +1/+1 counter on each creature you control. Each opponent may put a +1/+1 counter on each creature he or she controls. For each opponent who does, put a +1/+1 counter on each creature you control.

[*Titania's Boon*](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=8819)

> Put a +1/+1 counter on each creature you control.

As [**Mephy**](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/10440/mephy) pointed in his comment, [*Gavony Township*](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=233242) can also be used to give all your creatures a +1/+1 counter.

> **{2}{G}{W}, {T}**: Put a +1/+1 counter on each creature you control.

Comment: Gavony Township is very good at it because its a land, allowing you to have more spells in the deck.

Comment: any reason for a downvote?

Comment: I like using a combination of Battlefield Thaumaturge and Thrive.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the advanced features of the Gatherer to search for the phrase "put a +1/+1 counter on each", in quotes, in the rules text.

> http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[%22Put%20a%20%2b1/%2b1%20counter%20on%20each%20creature%20you%20control%22]

This finds **every single card** that puts a +1/+1 counter on each creature you control, and it will continue to do so as new sets are added.

Answer (score -4):

[Vigor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=vigor), is a good 6 drop that will give you what you need for the krenko.